# What is the purpose of Verbatim Identifiers in a program?

Tags: c#, identifier

What is the purpose of Verbatim Identifiers in a program?

I mean, why wouldn't I use a variable with different name instead? I am not clear about the use of Verbatim Identifiers. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Hope this helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim. I think a Google search could help here.

Comment: in most cases it is used for a better understanding and reading of the provided code. Sometimes you clearly will name a variable like "case" for example, because that describes their value best. every other name is like eating pommes frites with a spoon, working, but it really feels bad

Comment: Please note that all names, variables, methods, types, all the names are **identifiers**. Your question would become clearer more quickly if you used **verbatim** identifiers everywhere you just use *identifiers* right now.

Answer (score 4):

From: https://ericlippert.com/2013/09/09/verbatim-identifiers/

> The answer is straightforward. Imagine that we are back in the day when C# 2.0 just shipped. You have a C# 1.0 program that uses yield as an identifier, which is entirely reasonable; “yield” is a common term in many business and scientific applications. Now, C# 2.0 was carefully designed so that C# 1.0 programs that use yield as an identifier are still legal C# 2.0 programs; it only has its special meaning when it appears before return, and that never happened in a C# 1.0 program. But still, you decide that you’re going to mark the usages of yield in your program as verbatim identifiers so that it is more clear to the future readers of the code that it is being used as an identifier, not as part of an iterator.

Hope will help you.

Comment: Be sure to include attribution when directly quoting a post.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating and i will try to make it more useful and in appropriate way as by my experience and  suggestion pvoided by experienced user like you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation: https://ericlippert.com/2013/09/09/verbatim-identifiers/

Another is that this solves the problem if you (for any reason) **really** want your variable to be called for instance "object" (then you name it `@object`).